# MySQL Error Reporting in PHP - getting blank page instead of errors

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I cloned a test site for Joomla under SiteGround to WAMP. It runs fine, except for this problem. On SiteGround if I have an SQL error, it shows a page with the error and the SQL statement. On WAMP, I just get a blank page.

I assume I'm missing an Apache parameter somewhere to turn on MySQL error reporting, but I cannot find it after searching here and elsewhere.

Here are the Apache php.ini error reporting parameters:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On 
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
```

Comment: Have you restarted apache after modifying php.ini?

Comment: There is no such thing as "mysql error reporting" in apache or php. There is only error reporting and it is a question of how the mysql error is captured in php, whether it will be displayed by php or not.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your PHP code that is running the MySQL query?

Comment: I have this strange feeling of `mysql_*` functions being used on a WAMP installation with PHP7..

Comment: I am using the Joomla MySQL db interfaces, and the Joomla installation is cloned exactly from the SiteGround website to WAMP. So Joomla/PHP/Apache are deciding whether to display the error or a blank page. Clearly not Joomla, as it and its parameters are identical to SiteGround. I am using PHP 5.6.

Comment: And yes, I restarted both Apache and MySQL after making any php.ini or other config mods.

Comment: Well, try this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings?rq=1

Comment: Does siteground set a default error page where you have not imitated that on your local setup? Something along the lines of `ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html`